# cucumber end of file reached (EOFError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Running cucumber tests give me following error

```
  end of file reached (EOFError)
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1406:in `block in transport_request'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `catch'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `transport_request'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1376:in `request'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `block in request'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:58:in `each'
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:58:in `/^action$/'
  features/myFeature.feature:18:in `Then I should XY'
  Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
  /usr/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
  ./features/support/env.rb:45:in `After'
```

My gemlist from bundle:

```
* activemodel (4.2.6)
* activerecord (4.2.6)
* activesupport (4.2.6)
* addressable (2.4.0)
* arel (6.0.3)
* builder (3.2.2)
* bundler (1.6.5)
* capybara (2.6.2)
* childprocess (0.5.9)
* cucumber (2.3.3)
* cucumber-core (1.4.0)
* cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
* data_magic (0.22)
* diff-lcs (1.2.5)
* faker (1.6.3)
* ffi (1.9.10)
* gherkin (3.2.0)
* headless (2.2.3)
* i18n (0.7.0)
* json (1.8.3)
* mime-types (3.0)
* mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
* mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
* minitest (5.8.4)
* multi_json (1.11.2)
* multi_test (0.1.2)
* mysql2 (0.4.3)
* nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
* page-object (1.1.1)
* page_navigation (0.9)
* rack (1.6.4)
* rack-test (0.6.3)
* rspec (3.4.0)
* rspec-core (3.4.4)
* rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
* rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
* rspec-support (3.4.1)
* rubyzip (1.2.0)
* selenium-webdriver (2.53.0)
* snapurl (0.0.3)
* syntax (1.2.0)
* thread_safe (0.3.5)
* tzinfo (1.2.2)
* watir-webdriver (0.9.1)
* websocket (1.2.2)
* xpath (2.0.0)
* yml_reader (0.7)
* zip-zip (0.3)
```

OS: openSuSE 13.1
Browser: Firefox 45.0

The error occurs inside a each loop (after 1 till 2 minutes), regardless if I watch the Firefox or let it run headless.

Step Code (from pastebin link in comments)

```
Then /^I should XY$/ do
  today = Date.today
  heute = today.to_s.sub(/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/, '\\3.\\2.\\1')
  letzter_tag = Date.today.end_of_month
  differenz = letzter_tag - today
  ueber_naechster_monats_beginn = Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.next_month.next_month
  deutscher_ueber_naechster_monats_beginn = ueber_naechster_monats_beginn.to_s.sub(/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)/, '\\3.\\2.\\1')
  puts 'Heute ist das Datum: '+today.to_s
  puts 'Der letzte Tag des aktuellen Monats ist: '+letzter_tag.to_s
  puts 'Bis zum letzten Tag des aktuellen Monats sind es noch: '+differenz.to_s+' Tage'
  if differenz < 9 || differenz < 0
    puts "Der Monatswechsel liegt an, das neue Datum für den Monatsbeginn ist: "+ueber_naechster_monats_beginn.to_s
  else
    puts "Kein Monatswechsel liegt an."
  end
  tabellen_zeilen = @browser.table(:id => 'tabellenanfang').tbody.rows
  puts tabellen_zeilen.count.to_s+' Tabellenzeilen gefunden'
  link_list_2_mit_monats_wechsel = Array.new
  link_list_2_ohne_monats_wechsel = Array.new
  link_list_2 = Array.new
  link_list_1 = Array.new
  tabellen_zeilen.each do |tabellen_zeile|
    if !tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 2).div.text.include?("nicht veröffentlicht")
      link_list_2 << tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 0).div.a.text
      puts 'veröffentlicht: '+tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 0).div.a.text
      beginn_datum = Date.parse(tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 3).div.text)
      puts '  Beginn Datum ist: '+beginn_datum.to_s
      aktuelle_differenz = beginn_datum - today
      puts ' '
      # 
      if aktuelle_differenz < 10 || aktuelle_differenz < 0
        link_list_2_mit_monats_wechsel << tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 0).div.a.text
        puts "  "
      else
        link_list_2_ohne_monats_wechsel << tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 0).div.a.text
        puts "  "
      end
    else
      link_list_1 << tabellen_zeile.cell(:index => 0).div.a.text
      puts ' '
    end
  end
  puts ' '
  link_list_2.each { |link_text|
    puts '____________________________________________________________________________________________'
    puts ''
    puts link_text
    puts ''
    puts '____________________________________________________________________________________________'
    link = @browser.link(:text => link_text)
    begin
      link.click
    rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException => i #catch the Exception
      @browser.refresh
      link.wait_until_present(600)
      link.click
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{i}"
    end
    puts '    Link geöffnet'
    begin
        @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').wait_until_present(600)
        @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').click
    rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, TimeoutError => j #catch the Exception
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').wait_until_present(600)
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').click
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{j}"
    end
    puts ' '
    @browser.element(:id => 'begin_field').wait_until_present(600)
    @browser.element(:id => 'begin_field').exists?.should == true
    @browser.text_field(:id => 'begin_field').set heute
    @browser.element(:id => 'speichern_unten').wait_until_present(100)
    @browser.input(:id => 'speichern_unten').click
    begin
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab2').click
    rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException => e #catch the Exception
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab2').wait_until_present(100)
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab2').click
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{e}"
    end
    puts ' '
    begin
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').wait_until_present(100)
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').exists?.should == true
      @browser.text_field(:id => 'begin_date').set heute
    rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, TimeoutError => l #catch the Exception
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').wait_until_present(100)
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').exists?.should == true
      @browser.text_field(:id => 'begin_date').set heute
    end    
    begin
      @browser.element(:id => 'speichern_unten').wait_until_present(600)
      @browser.input(:id => 'speichern_unten').click
    rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, TimeoutError => h #catch the Exception
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{h}"
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.element(:id => 'speichern_unten').wait_until_present(600)
      @browser.input(:id => 'speichern_unten').click
    end    
    begin
      @browser.element(:id => 'tab1').wait_until_present(600)
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').click
    rescue Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException, TimeoutError => g #catch the Exception
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{g}"
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.element(:id => 'tab1').wait_until_present(600)
      @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').click
    end
    puts ' '
    begin
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_field').wait_until_present(600)
    rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError => k
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{k}"
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_field').wait_until_present(600)
    end
    @browser.element(:id => 'begin_field').exists?.should == true
    @browser.element(:id => 'begin_field').html.include?(heute).should == true
    @browser.element(:id => 'tab2').wait_until_present(600)
    @browser.input(:id => 'tab2').click
    begin
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').wait_until_present(100)
    rescue Watir::Wait::TimeoutError => f
      puts "Objekt konnte nicht geklickt werden: #{f}"
      @browser.refresh
      @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').wait_until_present(100)
    end
    @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').exists?.should == true
    @browser.element(:id => 'begin_date').html.include?(heute).should == true 
    puts '    neuer Veröffentlichungszeitraum auf '+heute+' gesetzt'
    @browser.link(:text => 'buttonText').click
    puts '____________________________________________________________________________________________'
    puts ''
  }
  puts ' '
  puts "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  puts ' '
  puts ' '
  puts ' '
  puts ' '
  link_list_2_mit_monats_wechsel.each { |monats_wechsel_link_text|
    puts '____________________________________________________________________________________________'
    puts ''
    puts monats_wechsel_link_text
    puts ''
    puts '____________________________________________________________________________________________'
    link = @browser.link(:text => monats_wechsel_link_text)
    link.click    
    puts '    Link geöffnet'
    @browser.input(:id => 'tab3').click   
    puts '    Reiter 1 Stelleninfo geöffnet'
    @browser.element(:id => 'dateField').wait_until_present(600)
    @browser.element(:id => 'dateField').exists?.should == true
    puts ' '
    @browser.text_field(:id => 'dateField').set deutscher_ueber_naechster_monats_beginn
    @browser.input(:id => 'speichern_unten').click
    sleep 1
    @browser.input(:id => 'tab1').click
    sleep 1
    @browser.input(:id => 'tab3').click   
    puts '    Reiter 1 Stelleninfo zur Kontrolle geöffnet'
    sleep 1
    @browser.element(:id => 'dateField').wait_until_present(600)
    @browser.element(:id => 'dateField').exists?.should == true
    @browser.element(:id => 'dateField').html.include?(deutscher_ueber_naechster_monats_beginn).should == true
    puts ' '
    @browser.link(:text => 'buttonText').click
    puts '____________________________________________________________________________________________'
    puts ' '
  }
  puts ' '
end
```

env.rb  (from pastebin link in comments)

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
# active_support wird fuer die Funktion end_of_month benoetigt
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
#require 'ruby_gntp'
require 'net/http'
#require 'escape_utils'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
World(PageObject::PageFactory)
require 'headless'
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 600 # seconds – default is 60
Capybara.run_server = true #Whether start server when testing
Capybara.default_selector = :css #default selector , you can change to :css
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 180 #When we testing AJAX, we can set a default wait time
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false #Ignore hidden elements when testing, make helpful when you hide or show elements using javascript

Before do
  @headless = Headless.new()
  @headless.start
  $DEBUG = true

  #profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  @browser  = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :http_client => client
  #@browser = Watir::Browser.new
  @browser.window.resize_to(2250, 1024)
end


After do
   @headless.destroy
   #@browser.close
end
```

What could I try?

Comment: Show the step that has the error.

Comment: here is my step, line 1 is line 15 in my script: http://pastebin.com/Z7LEw2Lk

Comment: The error occurs most of the time while doing the second or third index in the loop

Comment: and this is my env.rb http://pastebin.com/txxgkntx

Comment: Are you running tests in parallel?

Comment: No, I run them one after another

Comment: In that case I don't know how to fix it. Sorry. But I suggest to try to set custom port for capybara like: Capybara.server_port =10001 or even Capybara.server_port =10000 + rand(1000). That's because "connection refused" error may be easily caused by occupied port (for example because browser is not properly unloaded on headless.destroy). That's a weak idea but if you will try you will lose nothing. Good luck.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I will try it next time I work with this sytem

Comment: That's the most complicated 'step' I've ever seen in 8 years of using cucumber.   Your use of the tool seems way outside the intent of cucumber.  Also they way you are doing things makes it hard to know what 'failed' when something goes wrong.    I'd strongly suggest you pick up "The Cucumber Book" from Pragmatic Programmers and read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link did the trick: https://watirmelon.com/2013/05/16/stop-firefox-auto-updating-and-breaking-your-ci-build/

With global debug enabled I could see, that a h264 addon inside Firefox was trying to update and breaking the build.

Thanks four your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out. In your env.rb you are setting up capybara but you are creating browser using watir. That's not good because capybara and watir at the same time may produce a conflict. Switch Capybara off. Use only watir. Do not put 'capybara' to require. That's much more good suggestion than mine suggestion in a comment. But I am still not 100% sure. Try it please.

Comment: Agreed, I would use either Watir-webdriver or Capybara to drive the browser, but not both at once.

Comment: Running the test without capybara didn't help, even when I reduce the test to 2 clicks inside the iteration it fails :( Doing no click, only put the link text is ok.

Comment: Well. Now I am out of ideas. Please post the last version of env.rb and your code and I will think once again.

Comment: env.rb http://pastebin.com/6k94jvT3 my minimized step: http://pastebin.com/BHafb6A9

Comment: current error: http://pastebin.com/iP33u3fP whole time is 1.41 - 1.43 most of the time